# Spring + embedded Jetty + Apache Tiles: JSP not working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

Everything works fine separated (jsp work, Tiles work).
But when I'm trying to insert *.jsp value into tile, I get strange output:

- All content above the tile is lost (including head, other tiles, everything):

```html
        My footer
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried to exclude "jsp" servlet and got the same result. So, it seems, that page can't get compiled.

Simple values insertions works fine, the problem is only with jsp.

Comment: Please add the relevant lines of code.